# GDT Flush fails the entire kernel

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev, gdt

I am writing an x86_32 bit kernel from scratch in C, after writing a VGA driver, I have been trying to implement the GDT as well as the interrupts for a keyboard driver. However, my GDT_flush() function that is being called from assembly **fails and it results in a bootloop**. commenting that function, and it boots just fine( but without the GDT obviously ).

I am simulating the kernel on Qemu, and using a target specific toolchain to compile and link all the files together.

GDT.c:

```
struct gdt_entry{
  unsigned short limit_low;
  unsigned short base_low;
  unsigned char base_middle;
  unsigned char access;
  unsigned char granularity; 
  unsigned char base_high;
}__attribute__((packed));


struct gdt_pointer{
  unsigned short limit;
  unsigned int base;
}__attribute__((packed));

struct gdt_entry gdt[3];
struct gdt_pointer gdtptr;

//extern void flush_gdt(unsigned char gdtptr);
extern void flush_gdt();

void set_gdt_gate(int num, unsigned long base, unsigned long limit,unsigned char access,unsigned char gran){
  gdt[num].base_low = (base & 0xFFFF);
 gdt[num].base_middle = (base >> 16) & 0xFF;
  gdt[num].base_high = (base >> 24) & 0xFF;

  gdt[num].limit_low = (limit & 0xFFFF);
  gdt[num].granularity = (limit >> 16) & 0x0F;
  gdt[num].granularity |= (gran & 0x0F);

  gdt[num].access = access;
}

void init_gdt(){
  gdtptr.limit = (sizeof(struct gdt_entry) * 3) - 1;
  gdtptr.base = (uint32_t)&gdt;

  print_string("setting up kernel segments \n");
  set_gdt_gate(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Null segment
  set_gdt_gate(1, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x9A, 0xCF); //Code segment
  set_gdt_gate(2, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x92, 0xCF); //data segment
  print_string("kernel segments have been setup hehehhehehe\n");
  //flush_gdt((unsigned char)&gdtptr);
  flush_gdt();
}
```

descriptor.asm:

```
global flush_gdt
[extern gdtptr]

flush_gdt:
  ;mov eax, [esp + 4]
  ;lgdt[eax]
  lgdt[gdtptr]
  mov ax, 0x10
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  mov fs, ax 
  mov gs, ax
  mov ss, ax
  jmp 0x08: .flush_two 

.flush_two:
  ret
```

I looked up other similar projects and my implementation isn't very different. I've been trying to solve it for a couple of weeks now, any help is very appreciated.

thanks :)

I have tried passing the descriptor pointer as an argument to the function being called, but that also results in a bootloop.

Here is the QEMU log file:

```
0: v=0d e=0010 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0010:0000000000100d3b pc=0000000000100d3b SP=0018:0000000000104f1c env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000100010
EAX=00100010 EBX=001066c8 ECX=000003d5 EDX=000003d5
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00104f38 ESP=00104f1c
EIP=00100d3b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     696c6261 00006e65
IDT=     00000000 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00104f10 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     1: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0010:0000000000100d3b pc=0000000000100d3b SP=0018:0000000000104f1c env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000100010
EAX=00100010 EBX=001066c8 ECX=000003d5 EDX=000003d5
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00104f38 ESP=00104f1c
EIP=00100d3b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     696c6261 00006e65
IDT=     00000000 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000010 CCD=00104f10 CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
```

edit:

here is the github repo:

https://github.com/MadhavBh/FilterCoffee

apologies for the messy code :') Still very new at this.

Comment: Bochs' built-in debugger can pretty-print GDT entries so you can check that it means what you intended.

Comment: Which instruction is at address `00100d3b`?

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  There are too many different things that could be wrong in the calling code, compilation and linking process, kernel loader, etc, none of which we can see.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are seeing using the code in Github

Answer (score 0):

```
gdt[num].granularity = (limit >> 16) & 0x0F;
gdt[num].granularity |= (gran & 0x0F);
```

You have the the granularity bits and limit bits being mashed into the same 4 bits. The second line should possibly read:

```
gdt[num].granularity |= (gran & 0xF0);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I fixed the masking  and the AVL bit, however Qemu still crashes. would the qemu log ( -d int ) help in figuring out the error?

Comment: @MadhavBhatnagar apologies, I had mixed up the AVL bit with the P (present) bit. You don't need AVL set. The qemu log may help.

Comment: just added the qemu log file to the main post.

Comment: @MadhavBhatnagar `GDT=     696c6261 00006e65` looks odd - that's not the limit it should be. It's very difficult to see what is wrong from what you've posted. Do you have the full code (including linker scripts etc) in a repo?

Comment: @davmac: Indeed that spells `ablien\0\0`.  I think you passed a string pointer by mistake, or else your assembler/linker has the wrong idea about the addresses where things are located.

Comment: @NateEldredge good observation, though the limit is before the base so it's actually "enabli" (the displayed `0000` is not part of the limit value, which is only 16 bits). Looks like part of "enabling" perhaps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was caught up in some college assignments. 

I re-checked the pointers passed in my code, found nothing out of place.
I'm pretty sure there is an issue with the linker file, I'm not VERY familiar with ld files so im researching right now. 

I added the github repo in the main post.